# Reload Apache from a Python script

Tags: python, apache

I want to reload my apache server using a Python script. What will that be?

I know the terminal command , ie

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

This is what I tried:-

```
import os
c = "sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload"

os.system(c)
```

says `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

**How can I reload my server ?**

Comment: Is this "python script" going to be run by hand or in a cron job or by some other automated process whereby it will be difficulty to enter in the user's sudo password?

Comment: A URL will be hit in this case, which will reload the server. Also I dont want the user to enter the password.

Comment: Then this question is more about configuring passwordless sudo and less about how to run a subprocess in Python.

Comment: OK. So, how will I do that?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removed `sudo` and tried, it worked

```
import os
c = "/etc/init.d/apache2 reload"

os.system(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

2021 here. I could use sudo, even with vanilla apache2 installation.

```
import os
c = "sudo service apache2 restart"
os.system(c)
```